Calculation of Minkowski space energy density with cosmological constant
I’m calculating the stress-energy-momentum densities of Minkowski space ($g_{\mu\nu}=\mathrm{diag}(c^2,-1,-1,-1)$) and in doing so go to the Einstein field equations since they are easy to solve in this case. I find that $G^{\alpha\beta}=0$, so
$$\Lambda g^{\alpha\beta}=\kappa T^{\alpha\beta}$$
and since $g^{\alpha\beta}=\mathrm{diag}(c^{-2},-1,-1,-1)$ I find the energy density to be $T^{tt}=\frac{\Lambda}{\kappa c^2}$. This is all well and good, but I find that that value is more frequently quoted as the mass density with the energy density being quoted as $\approx\frac{\Lambda}{\kappa}=T^{tt}c^2$ (with $T^{tt}$ being the value I calculated); see here.
Which of these values $\frac{\Lambda}{\kappa}$ or $\frac{\Lambda}{\kappa c^2}$ is the correct value for energy density of the Minkowski metric with the cosmological constant, and if the former what have I done wrong in the calculation of the stress-energy tensor using the EFEs?

The EFEs are to be solved, not to be constrained by an unphysical assumption. You have a cosmological constant, so you cannot have $G_{\mu \nu}=0$, instead, you should have at least $G_{\mu \nu}+\Lambda g_{\mu \nu}=0$ in absence of ordinary matter, and afterward, interpret $G_{\mu \nu}=-\Lambda g_{\mu \nu} \equiv \kappa T_{\mu \nu}$.

@JeanbaptisteRoux although true that’s different by a sign. I would get the exact same result if I used that and then flipped the metric signature from (+,-,-,-) to (-,+,+,+).
